# How to fix Excel file with both extensions .xlsb.xlsm

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with vba that was recovered by Excel after the software closed unexpectedly and it now has two extensions: .xlsb.xlsm

I have tried googling what to do in this situation, but I can only find information on each extension separately and not when both are in the same file.

**Actions:** To fix the situation I tried:

1) Simply erasing the .xlsb extension

2) saving it as a .xlsm file and changing its name

**Results:** Either keeping both extensions, erasing one or doing 'save as' with a different name result in the same thing: the file opens as expected and seems to be functioning normally.

**I would like to know:**

1) Is it safe to keep the file with both extensions (though it seems only the last one is being recognized by excel)?

2) Why did it get the unexpected .xlsb extension?

3) Does it change anything in the file?

4) Is there a better approach to such a situation than the ones I took?

Comment: It’s just an extension. As long as you pick the right one and the file isn’t corrupt, it should come good. A file can only contain one extension at any one time.

Comment: The right-most ".xlsm"  is the extension it has now.  Anything to the left of that is part of the file's name.  In this case, it seems like the file's name has one or more dots in it which are permissible.  Most any strings are possible in the file's name, and this one has  "aaaazzzz.xlsb"